# Sharepoint Client Object Model: Load items from list with included File.ServerRelativeUrl

Tags: sharepoint, include, client

I'm trying to load `File.ServerRelativeUrl` when loading items from list, but no luck.

Trying this code:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> EnumListItems(List list, Folder folder)
{
    if (folder == null)
        return null;

    var camlQuery = new CamlQuery
    {
        //  ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>",
        FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl//"Relative path to folder '); -> Add relative Path for your Folder. for e.g.  "/Lists/ListName/FolderName"
    };

    var collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

    var result = Context.LoadQuery
    (
        collListItem.Include
        (
            item => item,
            item => item.File,
            item => item.File.ServerRelativeUrl
            //item => item["Body"]
        )
    );

    Context.ExecuteQuery();
    return result;
}
```

But no luck, when accessing `ServerRelativeUrl` I receive:

> 'item.File.ServerRelativeUrl' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And answer is - list is not document list, then File always null and not initialized.

Here an example get relative url of item attachmetns (and what I need, in the end)

```
string.Format(
  @"{0}/Attachments/{1}",
  list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
  item.Id
)
```

And list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl loaded by that

```
var result = Context.LoadQuery
        (
            collList.Include
            (
                list => list.Title,
                list => list.Id,                    
                list => list.RootFolder,
                list => list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
                list => list.Fields
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope it may help someone.  When iterating list items for a document library, you can get the file's server relative URL with the example code below:

```
var fileRef = Convert.ToString(listItem["FileRef"]);
```

Comment: It solved my problem for which I was looking from last 2 days.